# How do I know what target Architectures to choose?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, cpu-architecture

I am building my `Xamarin.Android` project and I have selected `AOT` compilation which has bloated my .apk to 165mb.

To get my .apk size down I am looking at the target architectures, currently I target:

> armeabi, armeabi-v7, x86, arm64-v8a

But I have no idea how these architectures correspond to modern devices.

I have read [Android CPU Architectures](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/cpu_architectures/#How_to_Specify_Supported_Architectures) and it says:

> Xamarin.Android defaults to armeabi-v7a for Release builds. This
>   setting provides significantly better performance than armeabi. If you
>   are targeting a 64-bit ARM platform (such as the Nexus 9), select
>   arm64-v8a. If you are deploying your app to an x86 device, select x86.
>   If the target x86 device uses a 64-bit CPU architecture, select
>   x86_64.

Therefore do I need to target armeabi and armeabi-v7?

what archetectures should I target for a modern Android tablet and phone?

Comment: I depends upon you... say you exclude x86, then your app will not show up for users that have Intel-based devices (ASUS, Acer, Hp, Lenovo, Dells, etc.. Android tablets use Intel Atoms). What is the device number breakdown of ABIs currently in use? Google does not publish this statistic, they only publish API level statistics on their dashboard. Personally most of the clients I deal with publish separate APKs for each ABI, thus each APK is smallest possible for an Xamarin App. This adds more work to your build/publication process if you are doing it manually....

Comment: .... Exclude `arm64-v8a` and newer Nexus  will use `armeabi-v7a` but will run a little slower, etc... Publishing separate APKs for a single App Id: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: @SushiHangover I have a Nexus 9 in the office so I will try exclude `arm64-v8a` and see what happens. I am currently using `VSTS` and the [Google play extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) to publish my app. I don't think they allow you to upload multiple apk's for different ABI's which is annoying

Comment: I've also just realised I have a Lenovo tab in the office. Which probably wont work when `x86` is unchecked

Comment: Yep, Lenovo does have a few of ARM-based tablets now, but most are Atom based... In the long run, excluding ABIs from a single APK will reduce your potential user base, again, your choice based upon the app and its target market, the only real clients that I have that do not publish all the ABIs are ones that are targeting dedicated devices (i.e. intergated barcoding devices, Point-of-sale devices, etc... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`armeabi` is for older devices as most newer devices run `armeabi-v7`. Secondly, 64 bit devices can fallback to other ABIs. If you're concerned about the size, then your best choice is to create multiple apks:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/cpu_architectures/#Targeting_Multiple_Platforms

Although Google recommends a single APK, this is not always the case:

> Although we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible, doing so is sometimes not possible. To help you publish your application for as many devices as possible, Google Play allows you to publish multiple APKs under the same application listing. Google Play then supplies each APK to the appropriate devices based on configuration support you've declared in the manifest file of each APK.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: I found a list of [Android-x86 devices](http://www.android-x86.org/hardware-list) and from this [quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-modern-Android-phones-that-dont-support-armeabi-v7a) link it seems to suggest `armeabi-v7` was introduced in 2012 so `armeabi` must be for pre 2012 devices. I've added these links for anyone else. Correct me if I'm wrong. I ended up with `armeabi-v7` and `arm64-v8a` even so I am still 99mb so will need to investigate the links you posted